# AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-17-fd3d890ad0ef> in <module>()

Tags: sift, opencv, python

I have applied SIFT on colab to get feature detection and description by get old Opencv library using the below code:

```
!pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16
!pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = cv.imread(path+ 'Gibraltar1.jpg') # queryImage
img2 = cv.imread(path+ 'Gibraltar1.90.jpg') # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv.SIFT_create()
```

However, I have tried to run these code before I use SIFT, it shows me below **error message:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-fd3d890ad0ef> in <module>()
      1 # Initiate SIFT detector
----> 2 sift = cv.SIFT_create()

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'SIFT_create'
```

Answer (score 0):

SIFT is in the `xfeatures2d` module, and can be instantiated using:

```
import cv2
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(...)
```

See [this reference](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/) for more details about the move.

Note: this is valid for OpenCV versions between 3.x and 4.5.x, but probably not for newer versions -- SIFT will be moved back into the main repository ([details](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16736)).